# Breaking a word inside a circle span and still keep the circle

Tags: html, css

I have this span over a product image

[image]

```
<span class="wb_badge wb_badge-rounded wb_badge-bottomright" style="background-color:#dd9933;color:#ffffff;">TEST2TEST 3 HAHAHAHAHAHA</span>
```

Which has the following CSS:

```
.wb_badge {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wb_badge-rounded {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wb_badge-rounded::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

But I would really like to make the text break at some point so I can avoid these large and almost empty circles just because of some text. I tried with word-break but it didn't worked as expected. How can I make the text break at some point and still keep the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `word-break: break-all;`. Add this to you wp_badge class. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break?retiredLocale=de).

```css
.wb_badge {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* new! I added this lines below. */
  width: 100px;  /* new */
  text-align: center; /* new */
  word-break: break-all; /* new */
}

.wb_badge-rounded {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wb_badge-rounded::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="wb_badge wb_badge-rounded wb_badge-bottomright" style="background-color:#dd9933;color:#ffffff;">TEST2TEST 3 HAHAHAHAHAHA</span>
```

#### without editing css

```css
.wb_badge {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.wb_badge-rounded {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wb_badge-rounded::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<span class="wb_badge wb_badge-rounded wb_badge-bottomright" style="background-color:#dd9933;color:#ffffff; word-break: break-all;text-align: center;">TEST2TEST 3 HAHAHAHAHAHA</span>
```

Comment: But I don't need a fixed width. I can't set a fixed width because I don't know the badge's content. It might be 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 characters and I need to make sure it will always look like a circle.

Comment: @howtogeek24 you need a width. The width will trigger the breaking points. I edit my question and i make the word-break responsive. It means if the width decrease it will trigger wordbreaks.